Ensure DOM elements are ready before triggering GSAP animations with useGSAP in React
Is there any better way to rewrite my code without using setTimeout?
use useGSAP in React.
If I use console.log(parentRef) in child.tsx, it will get null.
parent.tsx
export default function Page() {
  const parentRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col p-6">
      <div
        className="flex h-20 shrink-0 items-end rounded-lg bg-dark-slate-gray p-4 md:h-52"
        ref={parentRef}
      >
        <Logo parentRef={parentRef} />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

child.tsx
export default function Logo({ parentRef }: LogoProps) {
  const container = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const setupAnimation = () => {
    const parentWidth = parentRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    gsap.to(container.current, { x: parentWidth, rotation: 10 });
  };

  useGSAP(
    () => {
      setupAnimation();
    },
    { scope: container }
  );

  return (
    <div
      className={`${lusitana.className} flex flex-row items-center leading-none text-wheat`}
      ref={container}
    >
      <GlobeAltIcon className="h-12 w-12 rotate-[15deg]" />
    </div>
  );
}

I tried adding setTimeout to my code, and it worked correctly. It ensures that parentRef elements are fully rendered before being accessed.
child.tsx
useGSAP(
  () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setupAnimation();
    }, 100);
  },
  { scope: container }
);

